Process Hierarchy Diagram using PowerDesigner and Problems
I'm having trouble building a Process Hierarchy Diagram and prefer the decomposition link with sub-processes to be displayed on the Vertical side NOT the Horizontal one. Please help me!
I've tried a lot of ways including the chatbot's support and SAP community but it's not what I expected.
What I currently obtain:

What it should be:


The expected display is interesting, but it seems specific to a 3-level decomposition, no? For my understanding, it would be better not to have an arrow on the side on the child process, only at the side of the grand-children. I don't remember anything looking like this in PowerDesigner diagrams, especially not in the Process Hierarchy Diagram, where the display (and edit) are heavily constrained...

The only option I can imagine is to either create a free diagram inside PowerDesigner, or generate a separate format (SVG or else) from an existing PHD... And generate it again when the PHD is modified.
